# Does iPhone 11 device contain multiple UWB receivers?

Tags: sensors, hardware, mobile-applications, uwb

**Does iPhone 11 device contain multiple UWB receivers?**

[Angle of Arrival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_arrival) (AoA) is often required for many applications for UWB enabled devices. I wonder if modern UWB enabled devices i.e. iPhone 11 contain multiple UWB receivers to support AoA or not?

Comment: how is this an IOT question?

Comment: @jsotola I think its a IoT question as OP asking for modern state of the art and ios is just an example. However, if you don’t think the question is appropriate for this site, could you suggest which SE site suites best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These systems use multiple antenna, not multiple distinct radios to compute angle of arrival based on time of arrival at each antenna.

It's probably worth noting that these radios tend to be SDR (software defined radios) which detect signals by doing frequency analysis on a whole chuck of spectrum, rather than running to a specific frequency. This makes ToA and AoA calcs relatively easier than trying to sync a high rate time source across multiple radios

Comment: Can the devices reliably detect inter-devices relative directions (UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT/SO ON) using state of the art technologies of AoA within couple of centimeters? Any reference or article link would be highly appreciated.